# PLESK not working after Coldfusion install

Tags: windows, iis, coldfusion, plesk

I have a WIN2008 server with IIS7 that is running PLESK 9.5.2 and after installing Coldfusion 9, we are unable to access PLESK. It keeps asking for a username and password. After doing some research, I read that you should be able to resolve the issue by going to Start > All Programs > Parallels > PLESK > Plesk Reconfigurator and selecting Coldfusion under "Check component and folder permissions." However, Coldfusion is not even listed as an option.

Does anyone know how I can add it to the list? Hopefully someone else has run into this before and knows a solution...

Comment: For anyone following this topic, this was an older issue from 2010 but as far as resolution: we did ultimately end up switching away from PLESK and eventually converted Coldfusion sites to PHP. No longer having this issue.

See comment below about CF9 & PLESK

Answer (score 1):

CF9 wasn't supported on Plesk (Windows ver) until 10.1.0.  See point 9 here in [Release Notes](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.1.1/release-notes/parallels-plesk-panel-10.1.1-for-windows-based-os.html#23).